# What's the URL to test a SOAP WCF web service?

Tags: wcf, soap

I'm very new to WCF SOAP.

Having successfully built a basic REST( web api) web service and tested it through a url (eg a GET on api/users/1 to return a user with id = 1 from database), I'm now attempting something similar with a WCF SOAP web service.

I don't want to build a proxy client. Ideally i'd like to just test within browser or using Fiddler.

Here's the ABC (Address, Binding, Contract) program.cs code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Step 1  Create a URI to serve as the base address.
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1234/WCFsoap");

        // Step 2 : Create ServiceHost (this will host the webservice)
        ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(UserLookupWebService), baseAddress);

        try
        {
            // Step 3 : Add a service endpoint.
            selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(IUserLookup),        //Contract
                new BasicHttpBinding(),        //Binding
                "newapi");       //Address (relative to selfhost url)
```

For example:

How would I call a findUser(int userId = 1) method within a UserLookupWebService class? And can i do this from a browser or Fiddler?

Comment: For SOAP, you have to build a proxy client.   Well, you might be able to get away with something else but it would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either create a proxy class using svcutil.exe and use that class to connect to your service:

```
svcutil http://localhost:1234/WCFsoap
```

Or use any SOAP test tool out there:

I really like [Soap UI](http://www.soapui.org/) but you can use as well [WCF Test client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example